# Menu Items unclickable in many software

Tags: globalmenu

The global menu items of many software in Ubuntu 13.10 are unclickable. Firefox menu items work fine, while GNOME Terminal global menu items are all unclickable except for "Change Profile" and "Set Charater Encodig". In gedit global menus, only "Highlight Mode" in "View" is clickable! What to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a bug in Unity. Subscribe to this bug report! Hopefully it'll get fixed soon.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1277888